# button not visible in linear layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUsername"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Where is my button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is XML file , I don't see my button anywhere? Why is that? 
What happen to button did I do something wrong? What am i missing? The button does not show up in design.
Thanks

Comment: Set height of TextInpitLayout from match_parent to wrap_content and you will see your button

Comment: It is not related to your issue but for the password inputedittext use something like: `<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:endIconMode="password_toggle"> <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
       ...
      android:inputType="textPassword"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set your `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`'s `layout_height` as `match_parent`. That's why you can't see the `button`. Set the `layout_height` as `wrap_content` like below.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```